# GnuCash expense piechart report not including expense account with negative value

Tags: gnucash

Using the Reports->Income & Expense->Expense Piechart report, it shows the total of all expenses for the given period as expected.  However, the total is incorrect as it appears to exclude expense accounts with a negative balance for  the period.  For example, I have a Taxes account and for the month I received a tax refund, the expense report total is off by the amount of the refund.  Is there a setting I'm missing that would correct this problem?

Comment: How would you reflect a negative amount in a pie chart?

Comment: The pie chart isn't the problem, the negative amount should be in the legend and definitely in the total for the period.  Otherwise, the report is just wrong and useless.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that there isn't a way to represent a negative number in a pie chart when the others are positive numbers.

A negative number can't be assigned a portion of the pie.

Comment: I understand the omission from the pie chart but it should not be omitted from the legend and the total expenses for the period.